# Changing value in ERB based on viewport size?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, mobile

I have this line in erb:

```
<% @testimonials.each_slice(3) do |testimonial_slice| %>
  ...
```

If this is being rendered on mobile, I simply need to change out the 3 with a 1:

```
<% @testimonials.each_slice(1) do |testimonial_slice| %>
```

I am guessing that the only way to do this is through JavaScript on detecting viewport size?

I also thought about copying and pasting this section twice (one with the value 3 and the other with 1) then simply doing a show/hide based on a media query, but that is not DRY.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you actually need to use CSS that displays one or three per *something* based on a `@media` query. (Or even just based on overflow.) Even if you need distinct borders, it’s still possible with some effort…

Comment: can i do that with just pure css? just add class / id tags to each line and go with the show/hide?

Comment: Probably! What does each slice produce?

Comment: well, it's pretty lengthy. it produces a video / image combination

Comment: Look at twitter bootstrap and how their grid system works on different viewports